# "Not a valid JAR" when running wordcount on the hadoop-examples jar file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I tried to run wordcount example but I got a jar file not valid error

```
hduser@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar wordcount /user/hduser/Text /user/hduser/Text-output
Not a valid JAR: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar
```

How can I fix it? Where can I find those example jar files? Actually I have source code for wordcount. How can I create a Jar file by myself?

```js
hduser@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /user/hduser/Text /user/hduser/Text-out
15/10/14 15:41:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/10/14 15:41:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/10/14 15:41:18 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/10/14 15:41:19 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/10/14 15:41:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/10/14 15:41:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1980044638_0001
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1980044638_0001
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1980044638_0001_m_000000_0
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/Text/Text:0+0
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
15/10/14 15:41:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
15/10/14 15:41:21 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
15/10/14 15:41:21 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
15/10/14 15:41:21 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1980044638_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /user/hduser/Text/Text
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:70)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1891)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1832)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1812)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1784)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:542)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:362)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /user/hduser/Text/Text
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:70)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1891)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1832)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1812)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1784)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:542)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:362)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1222)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1210)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1200)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:271)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:238)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:231)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1498)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:302)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:85)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:545)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:783)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): Path is not a file: /user/hduser/Text/Text
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:70)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1891)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1832)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1812)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1784)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:542)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:362)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:254)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1220)
 ... 21 more
15/10/14 15:41:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1980044638_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/10/14 15:41:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/10/14 15:41:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1980044638_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
15/10/14 15:41:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Comment: Here's an answer to how to create a jar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103004/java-command-line-jar-file

Else, if you're in Eclipse you can export a project as a runnable jar and the wizard will help you identify which main method is your entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path to the jar does not exist, so the CLI is complaining. Ensure you have the full path to the jar. My `hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.0.jar` is located at `/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.0.jar`, but if you're using a Cloudera distribution or anything then it may differ.

Regarding how to create a jar, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103004/java-command-line-jar-file) answer.

Comment: Hi, I find mine as /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar I vi it and find what inside is really messey. Is that normal? Is that a wordcount?

Comment: You don't `vi` a jar, it is the compressed java classes... If you want to run that jar, you have to provide the entire path.

Comment: hduser@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoo^Cmapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /user/hduser/Text /user/hduser/Text-output

Comment: aused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): Path is not a file: /user/hduser/Text/Text

Comment: But I have three txt files in that path. I can see them on hadoop hdfs interface

Comment: Sure. If my answer was any help at all, please kindly mark it as the solution.